# Problem installing libigraph1 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package, apt-get

In the purpose of using [tgen](https://github.com/shadow/tgen), I need to run the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install cmake libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-dev libigraph1 libigraph-dev
```

But I have the following problem

> Reading package lists Done
> Building dependency tree Done
> Reading state information Done
> E: Unable to locate package libigraph1

My system is running on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I searched for way to correct the problem or even workaround but found nothing.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Run your commands individually, one at a time (5 separate commands) .. It can be any of the packages or a dependency that are failing ..  And `apt-get` is deprecated .. Use just `apt`.  `sudo apt install cmake`   |    `sudo apt install libglib2.0-0`  |  `sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev`  |  `sudo apt install libigraph1`  |  `sudo apt install libigraph-dev`  --  Determine which one it really is .. And Google adding that program to your `apt` repository for installation.

Answer (score 0):

22.04 has libigraph2, not libigraph1
https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libigraph2